# Xcode Swift - App crashes when button pressed

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2

So the code that I have is linked to a storyboard with a button on it. The button was suppose to send out a sound effect called Laughing. But when the button is pressed. The app crashes and sends this error "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

```
    //
     //  ViewController.swift
     //  LaLaLaughing
     //
     //  Created by MightyShin on 5/16/16.
     //  Copyright © 2016 Reverze. All rights reserved.
     //

     import UIKit
     import AVFoundation

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func LaughSound(sender: AnyObject) {

        var alertSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Laughing", ofType: "mp3")!)

        do {
            // Preperation
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        } catch _ {
        }
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        } catch _ {
        }

        // Play the sound
        do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: alertSound)
        } catch _{
        }

        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        audioPlayer.play()
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the full stracktrace.

Comment: what is a stracktrace?

Comment: @RapidReverse copy and paste everything that the Xcode debugger shows when your app crashes

Comment: You don't say which line is the problem but it's probably because you're using Swift's "crash" operator: `!`.

Switch to code that checks whether the call is safe, like...
    `if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Laughing", ofType: "mp3") {
     var alertSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    } else {
     print("No such resource")
    }`

Comment: Check your IBOutlets. You may have connected that button to more than one IBOutlet.

Comment: Ok I have fixed the problem and the problem is I forgot some little parts in the code that I need to put in.

Answer (score 2):

Sigabrt usually concerns with connections. Check all your outlets and actions. A problem may have arose if you made an outlet and then changed its type say textfield to textView, or changed its name e.g.- nameDoctorLabel to doctorNameLabel.

You may also have manually written the IBoutlets and IbActions and forgotten to link them with their respective objects in storyboard.

Also check that there is a filled grey dot in the left of your IBAction.

Check your connections in the connections inspector.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @trojanfoe. He can't comment